# mock function to return different values each time

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm using NSubstitute to mock my dependencies in my SuT. What I want to do is providing multiple return-values for a specific function. So each time the function is called, it should return a different value. As of the docs I can just add the values comma-seperated as follows:

```
var row = Substitute.For<ITable>();
table.NextRow().Returns(returnThis, returnThis2, returnThis3)
```

This function is called in a loop in my SuT:

```
while((table.NextRow() != null)
{ ... }
```

Now I'd expect that loop to run exactly as many times as I provide args to the mock - so in the above case exactly three times. When it's invoked a fourth time, I'd expect the mock to return the default-value for whatever the return-type of `NextRow` is - so `null` in case of a `class`. In my actual case I don't have exactly three variables but just an array of values my function should return:

```
var myArray = new[] { returnThis, returnThis2, returnThis3 };
table.NextRow().Returns(myArray[0], myArray.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

When I run my SuT, the loop never terminates and eventually I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. `NextRow` will never return `null`, but just keeps returning fake-instances for the `ITable`-interface. How can I "stop" providing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you recognized the mock will keep returning fakes when you don't provide further ones. The fakes being returned are those of the last argument to `Returns`. So in the following code the variables `b` and `c` will be equal to two:

```
[Test]
public void T()
{
    var m = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
    m.MyInt.Returns(1, 2);
    var a = m.MyInt;
    var b = m.MyInt;
    var c = m.MyInt;
}
```

So afterall you need to explictely add a `null`-element into your array:

```
var rows = myArray.ToList();
rows.Add(null);
table.NextRow.Returns(rows[0], rows.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

From a pure .Net-centric view it may sound a bit strange that the default-value of a fake isn't the default-value of that type. However it makes sense, when you look at how NSubsitite is used in a fluent way:

```
var m = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
m.MyMember.AnotherMember.Returns(whatever);
```

When NSubsitite chosed to return `null` for reference-types, you'd need to add a further `Returns`-call to `m.MyMember` as well which will make our test-code pretty cluttered:

```
var m = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();
var a = Substitute.For<IAnotherInterface>();
a.AnotherMember.Returns(whatever);
m.MyMember.Returns(a);
```

However NSubsitite will just give you a default implementation for that members type, when you don't explictely provide one.